# rails returns no gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was thinking after I issue

`rails new myapp`

I would have got a directory of ready MVC myapp but my rails return a `new` folder without gemfile inside.
I am sooo confused what is going on with it ?

Comment: as I said, I got a folder named `new` and other folders inside but there aren't `gemfile` or `gemfile.lock`

Comment: seems like your using an old version of rails, check what version your using with rails -v

Answer (score 1):

If you create another application, there is the same?

Gemfiles are creating automatically when generating new Rails 3 applications but not with earlier versions (2.x).